# Get-WinEvent output is truncated

Tags: get-winevent

I want to get the records from the Event file but it keeps truncating the messages.

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-AppV-Client/Admin' -MaxEvents 5
```

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message

---

10/21/2021 2:29:20 PM        19102 Error            Getting server publishing data failed....
10/21/2021 2:29:20 PM        19203 Error            HttpRequest sendRequest failed....
10/21/2021 2:29:05 PM        19102 Error            Getting server publishing data failed....
10/21/2021 2:29:05 PM        19203 Error            HttpRequest sendRequest failed....
10/21/2021 2:28:50 PM        19102 Error            Getting server publishing data failed....

Comment: What does (Get-Host).UI.RawUI return in your PowerShell console?

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-Host).UI.RawUI


ForegroundColor       : -1
BackgroundColor       : -1
CursorPosition        : 0,0
WindowPosition        : 
CursorSize            : 
BufferSize            : 177,0
WindowSize            : 
MaxWindowSize         : 
MaxPhysicalWindowSize : 
KeyAvailable          : 
WindowTitle           : Windows PowerShell ISE